# How can I get the Total field to display only once instead of on change of every group?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

[image]

I have grouped my formula by my date field per month but why does it show in all the months (*via lookup table*)?

Perhaps there's something missing or wrong with my formula? This is its code:

```
  (Sum ({tblDates.TotalFuelSales}) + Sum({tblDates.TotalMotorOilSales})) -
  (Sum ({tblDates.TotalOperationalExpenses}) + Sum({tblDates.TotalMotorOilExpenses}) + Sum({tblDates.TotalFuelExpenses}))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is Sum ({tblDates.TotalFuelSales} will give you the grand total so for every date group you the same value... if you wish to get according to date grouping then your syntax shoukd be something like below.
Sum ({tblDates.TotalFuelSales}, {your date grouping})

Above is just an example check syntax when you apply... similarly apply to all fields in formula

Comment: Hello! I have tried removing all Sum and start with one Sum. So I tried Sum ({tblDates.TotalFuelSales}, {tblDates.Dates}) but it just gives an error "There must be a group that matches this field" in {tblDates.Dates}. I tried playing around with the code and I sometimes get "The ) is missing". Can you help me with the exact code?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont you want to see the Total for each month then you should place `@Profit` formula on the Report footer. It is currently on the Group Footer section so it will show on change of every group.

I would do it this way:

1) Right click every field on the Group Header and Insert Summary (Sum) on the group footer for each field. So you have five Summary fields on the Group Footer section.

2) Put my `Profit` formula in the Report footer section, use those summaries in the formula to get my totals.

This is assuming you want Profit to appear only once.

You can skip doing the Insert Summaries part, and directly include the Sum({Fields}, {tbl.Date_group}) in your Profit formula.